# Create Column by parsing string from another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes that I would like to join.

One dataframe is like this, where `syscode_ntwrk` is split up by dash.

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '1234 - ESPN'), 
        (2, '1234 - ESPN'),
        (3, '963 - CNN'), 
        (4, '963 - CNN'),
    ],
    ['id', 'col1'] 
)
```

And the other is in this format, where `syscode_ntwrk` is concatenated together.

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (100, '1234ESPN'), 
        (297, '1234ESPN'),
        (3989, '963CNN'), 
        (478, '963CNN'),
    ],
    ['counts', 'col1'] 
)
```

Is there a way in the 2nd dataframe to create a new column to match the first dataframe for `syscode_ntwrk`? `Syscode` will always be a group of numbers, and `ntwrk` will always be a group of letters, so is there a regex to add a space dash space in between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the groups and use `concat_ws` to convert the groups into what you want.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (100, '1234ESPN'), 
        (297, '1234ESPN'),
        (3989, '963CNN'), 
        (478, '963CNN'),
    ],
    ['counts', 'col1'] 
)

df.select(
    F.concat_ws(
        ' - ',
        F.regexp_extract('col1', '(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)', 1),
        F.regexp_extract('col1', '(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)', 2)
    ).alias('parsed')
).show()

+-----------+
|     parsed|
+-----------+
|1234 - ESPN|
|1234 - ESPN|
|  963 - CNN|
|  963 - CNN|
+-----------+
```